# Python parser for unix "ip address" command (iproute2)

Tags: python, parsing, unix, networking

**short version:**

is there a library to parse the output of the unix command:

```
ip address
```

If the answer is no, do you know any python networking library that I could use to speed up the development of a parser?

**Detailed explanation:**

I'm trying to build an open source abstraction layer to retrieve information from network devices with different protocols (SSH, SNMP, HTTP) to be used in wireless community networks, I started from SSH ([prototype here](https://github.com/nemesisdesign/nodeshot/blob/bb869960667f483569092e94a3e051f6abe07a23/nodeshot/networking/connectors/ssh/ssh.py)) and initially I found a parser for the "ifconfig" command, but the parser does not take into account many cases plus my networking friends told me the "ifconfig" has been deprecated and "iproute2" is the future.

So, before start to develop my own, I ask if anybody knows if there is any open source python parser for the output of the "**ip address**" unix command.
I just need to retrieve a list of interfaces, each interface being a dictionary or an object, with all the details contained in the output of the command (name, type, ip, mac, mtu, ecc).

The only thing I've found is this undocumented and unfinished github repo:
https://github.com/nwhalen/python-iproute2

Comment: Instead of parsing the output of a command line tool, I would first try to get the information directly from `/proc/net` - that's where the `ifconfig` or `ip` commands get most of their information from.

Comment: As for networking libraries to help you with this, check out the [`netifaces` module](http://alastairs-place.net/projects/netifaces/).

Comment: thx Lukas, keep in mind i'm not trying to retrieve the interfaces on the machine where python is installed, but on a remote machine.

Comment: Oh I see - so you SSH into a remote machine, and want to enumerate the interfaces? How would that work with SNMP and HTTP though, unless there's an SMNP agent / HTTP webserver running on that machine that provides that info?

Comment: That would not work with SNMP or HTTP indeed.

Immagine this:

device.connector.get_wireless_channel()

Translates to a series of ssh commands if the device is configured to use SSH, while it translates to an SNMP request (if supported) if SNMP is used, and so on.

I would like it to work in a similar way as an ORM works for databases.

Comment: and yes sorry, i misunderstood your question, if SNMP is in use an SNMP agent must be running on the remote machine. Same for HTTP, some firmwares offer a very simple JSON file with the info needed.

Comment: No problem, I think now I get it. Then parsing the output of `ip address` or `ifconfig` might actually be your best bet for the SSH backend. The [`pyparsing`](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) module could be helpful in parsing that output. I guess regular expressions would work too, but quickly could become unreadable.

Comment: One more thing though: Your friends are totally right about `iproute2` being the future. But on many systems, particularly embedded ones, you're still more likely to encounter the good old `ifconfig`, the `iproute2` package might not be installed. So if you want to make your abstraction layer portable, you'll probably have to account for both.

Comment: One more hint: The `-o` option (oneline) to `ip` might give you output that's much easier to parse. Sorry to put all this in comments, but I currently don't have the time to write up a decent answer that's portable, covers most of the cases and is tested.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your comments, keep posting info if you have more ideas, I will forward this to our mailing list

Answer (score 1):

You can use the python pyroute2 library:

```
from pyroute2 import IPRoute
ip = IPRoute()
ip.get_addr(label='eth0')[0].get_attr('IFA_ADDRESS')
```

For more information you can check here: http://pyroute2.org/pyroute2-0.3.14p4/iproute.html

Answer (score 1):

Please just use the python netifaces library.

pip install netifaces

## Usage

```
>>>import netifaces
>>>netifaces.interfaces()
['lo0', 'gif0', 'stf0', 'en0', 'en1', 'fw0']
>>>netifaces.ifaddresses('lo0')
{18: [{'addr': ''}], 2: [{'peer': '127.0.0.1', 'netmask': '255.0.0.0', 'addr': '127.0.0.1'}], 30: [{'peer': '::1', 'netmask': 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff', 'addr': '::1'}, {'peer': '', 'netmask': 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::', 'addr': 'fe80::1%lo0'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used scapy for packetforgery and network tricks,
for parsers I always use ast library e re (regexp) library, they're all in python stdlib.

instead of theese you can always do:

```
import socket
socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

...and all the sockets methods.